# Manage ubuntu 11.10 desktop from server webconsole

Tags: software-recommendation, package-management, landscape

Are there any alternatives to Ubuntu landscape as I want to manage ubuntu desktops of different version 10.04,11.04 and 11.10

Comment: I think no one can really answer the question in the current state: What exactly do you mean by "manage ubuntu desktop"? If you make this question more specific, e.g. ask about how to deploy an Ubuntu installation to many computers etc. you have a higher chance to get a useful answer.

Comment: Is this supposed to be asking the same as http://askubuntu.com/questions/57581/manage-100-ubuntu-client-from-single-instance ?

Comment: It is not an exact duplicate (it allows for landscape), but it answers the question. There are a couple of similar questions on the site, the one in the comment above is the one that I find most complete (most voted, better answers).

Answer (score 3):

With so many desktops, why don't you contact Canonical? They're experts. It's what they do. You're not saying why you're looking for an alternative to Landscape. You're actually not saying much at all.

If you just want to manage users, storage, etc, then an LDAP+NFS-setup might be appropriate and you have lots of software to manage those services. If you want to upgrade many computers at the same time, then it's possible to do that using ssh and some scripts. But until you provide more information about your needs and why Landscape isn't suitable, it's impossible to provide a detailed answer.

Comment: -1 - It doesn't answer the question - he is trying to stay away from landscape specifically.

Comment: NFS/LDAP doesn't have anything to do with Landscape though. And that really does save lots of time in certain instances. But the only thing he's saying is what tool he does not want to use in order to fix his problem. He doesn't say what the problem is. His question might be interpreted that he thinks Landscape cannot be used to manage desktops.

Answer (score 1):

Just a clarification: Landscape will manage those different Ubuntu versions just fine - from your wording it seems to indicate you think Landscape won't manage different Ubuntu versions.